# Which SIP response code should be used for maintenance mode

Tags: sip, maintenance-mode

A SIP response code for general maintenance purposes seems not to exist (*reference:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes).

What kind of **response code** ( 1xx/2xx/3xx/4xx or 5xx ) should be used for **maintenance mode**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

503 Service Unavailable, see RFC3261, chapter 21.5.4 ([Link](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3261.html)). BTW, you should retag the question, although the error code scheme is similiar, SIP and HTTP are different protocols